# re-entrancy vulnerability

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, ico

I have this code :

```
function finish(address _teamFund, address _ecosystemFund, address _bountyFund) public onlyOwner {

      require(!isFinalized);
      uint256 alreadyMinted = token.totalSupply();
      require(alreadyMinted < maxTokens);

      uint256 unsoldTokens = totalTokensForSale - alreadyMinted;
      if (unsoldTokens > 0) {
        tokensForEcosystem = tokensForEcosystem + unsoldTokens;
      }

      token.mint(_teamFund,tokensForTeam);
      token.mint(_ecosystemFund,tokensForEcosystem);
      token.mint(_bountyFund,tokensForBounty);
      finalize();
  }
```

Remix giving warning

```
</i>: Could potentially lead to re-entrancy vulnerability. <br/><i>Note:</i> Modifiers are currently not considered by this static analysis.
```

for these 3 lines :

```
uint256 unsoldTokens = totalTokensForSale - alreadyMinted;
          if (unsoldTokens > 0) {
            tokensForEcosystem = tokensForEcosystem + unsoldTokens;
          }
```

I tried with safemath also , but didn't get any success.

```
uint256 unsoldTokens = totalTokensForSale.sub(alreadyMinted);
    if (unsoldTokens > 0) {
      tokensForEcosystem = tokensForEcosystem.add(unsoldTokens);
    }
```

Comment: Probably your not checking underflow and overflow of integer. That will leads to unexpected results. Can you please post total code, so that I'll try to help you to resolve issues.

Comment: this is my complete code please have a look : https://gist.github.com/cmaliwal/6ff33c7d75886fc2f10948b41334de37